# Поиск элемента HTML, который содержит какой либо id

Tags: xpath, cssselect

Имеется корневой элемент tbody

В этом элементе имеются tr, необходимо найти tr, у которых есть какой-либо id.

Как это сделать с помощью CSS-селектора или XPath. Отсутствие класса, например я знаю как сделать, а как присутствие id?

Пример разметки:

```
<tr id="cpu1422" role="row" class="tablesorter-hasChildRow odd" style="display: table-row;">....</tr>
<tr class="tablesorter-childRow odd" role="row">...</tr>
<tr id="cpu1423" role="row" class="tablesorter-hasChildRow even" style="display: table-row;">...</tr>
<tr class="tablesorter-childRow even" role="row">...</tr>
<tr id="cpu1490" role="row" class="tablesorter-hasChildRow odd" style="display: table-row;">....</tr>
<tr class="tablesorter-childRow odd" role="row">...</tr>
<tr id="cpu1769" role="row" class="tablesorter-hasChildRow even" style="display: table-row;">...</tr>
```

Их можно найти либо брать только нечетные порядок, либо по style(эти варианты я и сам смогу). Но хотелось бы по id попробовать

Comment: Попробуйте с помощью `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew я использую Selenium

Comment: Так добавьте эту информацию в вопрос вместе с кодом, который не работает.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew какая разница, на чем я пишу, XPath и css-селекторы от этого не зависят

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew хоть на Lxml, какая разница.

Answer (score 1):

С помощью XPath это будет что-то типа:

```
//tbody/tr[@id="cpu1422"]
```

Если нужно вообще все с любым `id`:

```
//tbody/tr[@id]
```